# Python polynomial division - wrong remainder output

Tags: python-3.x, polynomials

I made this polynomial division program, and it works just fine for float() values.

The script is supposed to be called using cmd like this: `python main.py input.txt`

The file input.txt contains two lines of numbers which the script converts to two lists of polynomial coeficients. So when the first line of input.txt is , say, **1 5 3 7**, the script reads the line as **1x^0 + 5x^1 + 3x^2 + 7x^3**.

When the program reads the text.txt it does the division and prints out two lines, the first being the result and the second being the remainder.

So basically if input.txt contains these lines:

> 0 12 -2 -4

> 3 -2

The program prints:

> 0 4 2

> 0

Where the first line is the result and the second one the remainder.

Now here's the code:

```
import sys
text = open(sys.argv[1])
dividend = list(text.readline().split())
divisor = list(text.readline().split())

for i in range(0, len(divisor)):
    divisor[i] = int(divisor[i])

for i in range(0, len(dividend)):
    dividend[i] = int(dividend[i])

def polynomial_division(dividend, divisor):
    divid = dividend
    divis = divisor[0]
    for v in range(len(dividend)-(len(divisor)-1)):
        divid[v] /= divis
        coef = divid[v]
        if coef != 0:
            for i in range(1, len(divisor)):
                divid[v + i] += -divisor[i] * coef
 
    separator = -(len(divisor)-1)
    output = (divid[:separator])
    remainder = (divid[separator:])

    print(*output, sep=' ')
    print(*remainder, sep=' ')

polynomial_division(dividend, divisor)
```

However my teacher said the output should be int() values, so I modified it with the `//` operator and now the output contains int() values.

```
import sys
text = open(sys.argv[1])
dividend = list(text.readline().split())
divisor = list(text.readline().split())

for i in range(0, len(divisor)):
    divisor[i] = int(divisor[i])

for i in range(0, len(dividend)):
    dividend[i] = int(dividend[i])

def polynomial_division(dividend, divisor):
    divid = dividend
    divis = divisor[0]
    for v in range(len(dividend)-(len(divisor)-1)):
        divid[v] //= divis
        coef = divid[v]
        if coef != 0:
            for i in range(1, len(divisor)):
                divid[v + i] += -divisor[i] * coef
 
    separator = -(len(divisor)-1)
    output = (divid[:separator])
    remainder = (divid[separator:])

    print(*output, sep=' ')
    print(*remainder, sep=' ')

polynomial_division(dividend, divisor)
```

But when the input.txt contains:

> 5 -3 6 2 -8

> 2 0 3 4

The output is:

> 2 -2

> 0 0 0

Which means the output is wrong as it should be:

> 2 -2

> 1 1

So my question is, what did I do wrong?

Comment: @KellyBundy you're right, sorry for the mistakes I'll fix it in the text, the program reads it as you said tho

Comment: Where does the (first) error happen? While preparing `divisor` and `dividend`, or in `polynomial_division`? In either case it would be good to reduce the code to the problematic part (e.g., if it's in the function, then hardcode `divisor` and `dividend` so we don't all have to create an extra file and run the whole thing from a command line). [mre]

Comment: Your original code seems to be working correctly. For the your second example, you can't write the coefficients as integers because they aren't, [see here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%285x%5E4-3x%5E3%2B6x%5E2%2B2x-8%29%2F%282x%5E3%2B3x%2B4%29). Your original code produces the correct output. For cases where the result isn't actually close to an integer, integer division will just result in truncation, which likely causes the incorrect remainder for your second code.

Comment: @Tyberius Nah, their first code has the same bug.

Comment: @KellyBundy I just ran their code with `dividend=[5, -3, 6, 2, -8]
divisor=[2,0,3,4]` and got `2.5 -1.5
-1.5 -3.5 -2.0` which is the right answer. It might still fail for other inputs, but at least that example is correct. What they wrote that it "should be" is incorrect, not least of which because the result does not have all integer coefficients and neither does the remainder.

Comment: @Tyberius That's not the right answer. Their "should be" is correct.

Comment: @KellyBundy I'm not seeing how that could be the case unless I'm really misinterpreting the problem. Check the link in my comment. Wolfram Alpha gives the same result as my comment, and the results there are just from running the first versions of their code. Their answer can't be right, `2 -2` would correspond to 2x-2, but if we multiply this by 2x^3+3x+4, you would get 4x^4 for the highest order term rather than 5x^4.

Comment: @Tyberius Remember that `1 5 3 7` means 1x^0 + 5x^1 + 3x^2 + 7x^3.

Comment: @KellyBundy haha okay I was missing a pretty important detail, sorry for all the back and forth. But that does at least help me recognize what is going wrong: their code seems to work fine for treating the coefficients with the convention I was using. So if they just reverse `dividend` and  `divisor`, as well as `output` and `remainder`, that seems to give the right result.